# CSV export with StreamedResponse

Tags: php, server, export-to-csv, symfony

I have to create a CSV export. I found this [awesome service](http://obtao.com/blog/2013/12/export-data-to-a-csv-file-with-symfony/) and I tried to adapt it to my case. This works very well on my own computer (windows 7, wamp 2.5 not modified) but when I put it on the server (Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, PHP 5.5.9), this doesn't work anymore. It seems that it tries to export an infinite flux of data and it might crash the server. I work on Symfony 3.1.1. Here is the code of my class :

```
public function exportCsv($affairesQuery, $em)
{
    $response = new StreamedResponse(function() use($affairesQuery, $em) {


        $results = $affairesQuery->iterate();
        $handle = fopen('php://output', 'r+');
        fputs($handle, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ));
        fputcsv($handle, [
            // My long list of headers
                ],
                ";");

        while (false !== ($row = $results->next())) {
            fputcsv($handle, $row[0]->toArray(), ";");
            $em->detach($row[0]);
        }

        fclose($handle);

    });
    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/force-download');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="Planning du '.date("Y-m-d h:i:s").".csv");

    return $response;
}
```

UPDATE :
I tried to make goodby/csv working in my case, as said in comment below, but I got exactly the same issue.  Which is very strange, because this isn't the same spirit.

```
public function exportCsv($affairesQuery, $em)
{


    $stmt = $this->dbConnection->prepare($affairesQuery->getQuery()->getSQL());

    $n = 1;
    foreach($affairesQuery->getQuery()->getParameters()->toArray() as $value)
    {
        $stmt->bindValue($n, $value->getValue());
        $n++;
    }
    $response = new StreamedResponse();
    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="Planning du '.date("Y-m-d h:i:s").".csv");
    $response->setCallback(function() use($stmt) {
        $config = new ExporterConfig();
        $exporter = new Exporter($config);

        $exporter->export('php://output', new PdoCollection($stmt->getIterator()));
    });
    $response->sendContent();

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: i suggest you to take a look at some exporter library ([goodby/csv](https://github.com/goodby/csv) or [thephpleague/csv](https://github.com/thephpleague/csv) ). In particularly [this goodby example](https://github.com/goodby/csv#export-in-symfony2-action)

Comment: I tried to make goodby/csv work correctly, but it requires a PDO object. And I'm unable to get it from a doctrine query. I can get the SQL, but without the parameters. Binding again theses would be quite long because I have 3 cases.